# Frequent Micro health care data

Tags: data-request, medical

I need a dataset with some health outcome (like immunization rates or reported disease cases) that is **both** frequent (weekly or more frequent) and micro-geographic (zip code or finer).

Comment: if you can live with state-counties, perhaps you can use seer  http://www.asdfree.com/2013/07/analyze-surveillance-epidemiology-and.html